# NSIS, progress bar not showing 100% on completion

Tags: nsis

I use NSIS to create installer . In my script `!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE`
so that user can see the installation file logs. 
But here my issue is even the progress text shows completed . progress bar underneath doesn't reflect 100%.
Please find this [image: screenshot]

issue happens only in windows 7 , in Windows Xp its fine.

AFAIK pidgin uses NSIS installer script and for that I could able to see its Progressbar showing 100 % when gets completed.

Comment: Voting to close because this is not a real question, and should rather be a [bug report in the NSIS Bug Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=373085&group_id=22049&func=browse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the progress bar goes to 100% on XP? Depending on the visual style, it might look like it is at 100% (You could try smooth progress bar (InstProgressFlags smooth) with "XPStyle off")

The usual cause of this is a return in a section:

```
Section
;some code here
${If} $x = $y
  return
${EndIf}
;some code here
SectionEnd
```

To work around a return problem you either change the code to use if/else blocks or put all of the logic in a function and call the function from the section.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using 'return' inside section, once you use 'return' ina a section, progressbar might 'jump' the progress from SectionEnd.

Relative jumps (aka GoTo) to negative positions on script might cause the same problem.